# How can I create a Navigation Rail that work togeter with a Navigation Drawer?

Tags: python-3.x, material-design, navigation-drawer, kivy-language, kivymd

My problem is this: I'm learning material design inside the kivymd. Seeing the [material design website](https://m3.material.io/), I noted that it use a Navigation Rail with a hover event for some buttons that add a Navigation Drawer. The image:

[image: Material design website]

So I trying to create it inside my python program with kivymd, but my problem is that when I move the hover, the navigation drawer stand above the navigation rail, like this:

[image: Before hover]
[image: After hover]

I tried to use pos, padding and spacing, but not change the position. The pos_hint works, but the navigation rail have a absolute size, so it don't solved. My resumed kv language:

```
MDNavigationRail:
    id: nav_rail
    selected_color_background: app.theme_cls.primary_color
    ripple_color_item: app.theme_cls.primary_color
    font_name: app.COMFORTAA
    on_item_release: root._item_clicked(*args)
    MDNavigationRailContent:

MDNavigationLayout:
    MDScreenManager:

MDNavigationDrawer:
    id: nav_drawer
    radius: 0, 16, 16, 0
    elevation: 0.5
    font_size: '16dp'
    font_name: app.COMFORTAA
    padding_x: '100dp'
    width: "240dp"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it! Before a lot of work and attempts, I got a way to do it with `pos_hint`:

```
<MyScreen>:
    MDFloatLayout:
        MDBoxLayout:
            size: root.size
            pos: root.pos
            MDNavigationRail:
                id: nav_rail
                [...]
            MDBoxLayout:
                MDScreenManager:
                    [...]
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            pos_hint: {'x': nav_rail.width / root.width}
            [...]
```

First I created a MDFloatLayout, to the MDNavigationDrawer can have a float position.

The pos_hint was the width from the MDNavigationRail divided by the width from the root, it will give me the rail end percent position, in relation to the root width.

Peraps these I needed to put the ScreenManager and the rail inside a Box Layout, like the guidance from documentation, and give the root size and position from the MDBoxLayout inside the MDFloatLayout.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: nice work, now i'm trying it in flutter.

Answer (score 1):

Great question! I'm wondering the same exact thing. If I figure it out, I'll post it here.

Comment: Hello Jimmy! Thank you for the motivation! I finded a way to solve this, you can read my answer below